# Choosing a multi-label classifier with high number of labels

Tags: keras, neural-network, classification, random-forest, multilabel-classification

First of all, I'm very new to ML and I have this task:

I need to build a ML model to give clients a list of 10 professions for each of them which best fit with their data: bachelor's degree type, favourite subjects, favourite professional sectors, etc...

My team and I have alredy extracted info from an SQL database and created a dataframe with all the relevant information and One Hot Encoded it: this is the result:

```
df_all_dumm.shape
(773, 1029)
```

So I have 773 clients and 1029 columns (a lot of them, but we thought it is necessary because all the columns were numeric categorical). Most of the columns are OHE professions columns (from 99 to 998), where there is "1" if the profession has been suggested to the client or "0" if not.

I'm a bit lost about if this dataset approach is fine for multi-label classification, about what method to use (NN, RandomTrees classif, scikit multi-learn models...). I have alredy tried with some multi-learn models like MLkNN or BRkNNaClassifier but the results are very poor (F1 Score = 0.1 - 0.2).

This is the dataset (it doesn't contain any private data, so I think there is no problem uploading it. Also, I don't know if this is the propper way to paste a link, sorry again)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nID4q7EfpoiNKdWz6N4FRUgIQEniwFRV/view?usp=sharing

EDIT:

I have created a Sequential Keras model:

```
# Slicing target columns from the rest of the df

data = pd.read_csv('df_all_dumm.csv')
data_c = data.copy()
data_in = data_c.copy()
data_c.iloc[:,99:999]
data_out = data_c.iloc[:,99:999]
data_in = data_in.drop(data_out.columns,1)
data_in = data_in.drop(['id'],1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_in,
                                                    data_out,
                                                    test_size = 0.3,
                                                    random_state = 42)

print("{0:2.2f}% of data in train set".format(len(X_train)/len(data.index)*100))
print("{0:2.2f}% of data in test set".format(len(X_test)/len(data.index)*100))

# Dataframes to tensors

X_train_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train.values)
X_test_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_test.values)
y_train_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train.values)
y_test_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test.values)

from numpy import asarray
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
 

# get the model
def get_model(n_inputs, n_outputs):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=n_inputs, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(600, input_dim=n_inputs, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(700, input_dim=n_inputs, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(900, input_dim=n_inputs, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
 
# load dataset
X, y = X_train_tf, y_train_tf
n_inputs, n_outputs = X.shape[1], y.shape[1]
# get model
model = get_model(n_inputs, n_outputs)
# fit the model on all data
model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.33, epochs=100, batch_size=10)


prec = model.evaluate(X_test_tf, y_test_tf)[1]
print("La precisión de la red es: {} %".format(round(prec*100,2)))

La precisión de la red es: 4.74 %
```

So, this is the model we created. I think the main problem here is that we have 900 different output labels and our data input size is 500...

We also thought about applying some clustering algorithm first to cluster the professions in, let's say 5 groups, train a NN for every group and then predict.

Comment: Which columns are your labels? It's totally fine to one-hot encode your categorical features (input data) but I had a look at your dataset and it's not obvious what you actually want to classify to i.e. take a single row, what is it that you want to predict from it?

Comment: My profession_X are the labels I want to predict from the other columns of a row.

This is how rows of the SQL database looks like:

[link] https://easyupload.io/utgxvc

The professions are the labels I want to predict with new clients.

Comment: Try a neural network and post your model and I'll take a look

Comment: I have edited the post with the neuronal network model, thanks for the help :D

Comment: Ah I've just seen it - your model looks good by the way, however you simply don't have enough data for that many labels, so no matter what you try it just doesn't have enough information to learn from. Can you get more data?

Comment: You could possibly try using Google BERT (https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html) as this is a pre-trained model and so typically you don't need as much data, however even then I'm not sure you'll have enough and it will take a while to configure it

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer! Well, this is just a Master's degree 96h internship in a start-up. They are considerably new and this the only verified data we can get... We could try clustering the professions by their sector (IT, Social) so instead of predicting the exact profession, we predict a group of them (i.e. IT professions), and maybe later apply a neuronal network?